# Event download as ICS file

Tags: aem

I've created a event using foundation event component (/libs/collab/calendar/components/event) and set the required values. But if I try to download the event ICS file then it's throwing following exception:

```
com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter Exception: null java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:769)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneRegistryImpl.getTimeZone(TimeZoneRegistryImpl.java:136)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.calendar.impl.JcrTimeZoneRegistry.getTimeZone(JcrTimeZoneRegistry.java:101)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.calendar.servlets.ICalExportServlet.doGet(ICalExportServlet.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:508)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:144)
```

It appears from the stacktrace that event timezone is set to null. I don't see how to set it or am missing anything else.

Thanks

Comment: Any codes that can be shared to us ?

Comment: Try setting default timezone. Documentation [covers this topic](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/social_communities/calendar_and_events.html#Defining%20Default%20Settings%20for%20Your%20Calendar).

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Create event on any page and there's a "Download event as ICS file" link in it (only in author mode), click on that link. Open the downloaded file and check if it contains ICS data or not.

Comment: @TomekRękawek Tried setting Timezone on calendar but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug on CQ side, following is the response that I got on Adobe forum:

```
Issue has been filled (CQ5-34388) internally.  As a workaround manually set the timezone. Ex:- for geometrixx "/content/geometrixx/en/events/shapecon/jcr:content/par/event/event" path create a property called "timeZone" of type "String" and assign value as "Asia/India" which is IST time zone.
```

So, the issue is because of "timeZone" not getting set with event. One of the thing that I noticed is, 'timeZone' does get set if you set time with date, say 11:00 AM to 1:00 PM on 12 Dec 2013. The issue is only if time is not set i.e. event is marked as full day event.